# The given key was not present in the dictionary Match Evaluator delegate

Tags: c#, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to *replace* a string with *regex* via `Match` Evaluator delegate. [dictionary method] when the string starts with: `.- &*?`. I get a error with the following details:

> the given key was not present in the dictionary.

What can I do?

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> ()
{
    { "-", "e"  },
    { "?", "z'" },
};

string str1 = "-50"
var p = new Regex(String.Join("|", dict.Keys));
str2 = p.Replace(str1, x => dict[x.Value]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-7.0) symbols (e.g. `?`) which have *special meaning* in regular expressions:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  { "-", "e"  },
  { "?", "z'" }, 
};

var pattern = string.Join("|", dict
  .Keys
  .OrderByDescending(key => key.Length)
  .Select(key => Regex.Escape(key)));

string str1 = "-50";

string str2 = Regex.Replace(str1, pattern, match => dict[match.Value]);
```

There is a little trick with `.OrderByDescending(key => key.Length)`: if we have pattern which is a *substring* of another one, say

```
{"--", "x2"},
{"-", "x1"},  // "-" is a substring of "--"
```

then we should try *longer* pattern *first*: `--abc` should be transformed into `x2abc`, not `x1x1abc`